# Can I create only one display name for Actions project?

Tags: actions-on-google

I created and published a project with a specific display name (already approved). After, I created another project using the direct name of my brand (1 name) and got approval for use. I would like that 2 projects use the same content but this second project was denied by "appers to spam users" (repetitive content).

Is there a way for me to link a "Display Name" variation to my original project?

Answer (score 0):

You may use different Display Names for different locale/language of a project, but there are no ways for using multiple Display Names for the exact same project.